# Building opencv with Intel Inference Engine

Tags: opencv, intel, inference-engine, openvino

Trying to load ssdlite v2 model with intel inference engine on raspberry Pi 3. For this, I need to build opencv-4.0 with Intel Inference API engine. I am unable to build open CV using CMAKE with  -DWITH_INF_ENGINE=ON ^
  -DENABLE_CXX11=ON flags. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First you need install or compile this engine, see you [Intel OpenVINO](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-RaspberryPI) documentation.

Comment: I have done that. But, I am not able to run opencv along with that. Especially, their dnn.readnet(xml, bin) #xml & bin files

Comment: Did you set backend? Here: cv.dnn_Net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_INFERENCE_ENGINE)